# Array Index Out of Bounds Exception - CSV Import

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV in a java program to a 2d array. Every time I test to see if it's been imported correctly it returns the correct result but also throws an Array Index Out of Bounds Exception (Index 45 out of bounds for length 45)

Here is the code and I appreciate any assistance.

```
public static String[][] readIn(String file){
    BufferedReader reader1 = null;
    BufferedReader reader2 = null;
      String line = "";
      int colCount = 0;
      int maxLen = 0;
      String[][] source = null;
     
      try {
       reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       while((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
           colCount++;
           String[] row = line.split(",");
           if (maxLen < row.length) {
               maxLen = row.length;
           }
           else {}
       }

       source = new String[colCount][maxLen];
       reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       
       for(int x = 0; x < colCount; x++) {
           line = reader2.readLine();
           String[] row = line.split(",");
           for (int y = 0; y < maxLen; y++) {
               source[x][y]=row[y];
           }   
       }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally {
       try {
        reader1.close();
        reader2.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
      return source;
}
```

Comment: The reason it still returns a result is because you catch the exception without re-throwing it or exiting the method early. So I can only assume what is returned is only a partial result. As for the exception, either use the debugger or add print statements so you can see for what line it throws. _Edit_ I see now you say it returns the correct result so maybe start by examining if you have an empty line at the and of the file (or some summary line)

Comment: Yes it seems like maxLen was the issue. I removed the inner for loop and replaced it with source[x] = row; which has fixed it. Thank you so much!